# Find a Regular Expression for the language accepted by the Finite Automata

Tags: regex, finite-automata, computation-theory

Find a Regular Expression for the language accepted by the Finite Automata

[image]

Comment: Homework? What have you tried?

Comment: What are the start and accept states?

Comment: I am not sure? How would I determine this?

Comment: @OSU it should be given in the problem. And this does seem like HW.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both your start and end state is `-`, your finite automata accepts strings like these: -

```
ab
aab
abb
aabb
aabbaaabbb
abaabbaaabbb
aaaabbbb
bbaaabbbaab
so on..
```

Note that, strings accepted by your automata will change based on `start` and `end` state. But that you can make out yourself.

Based on the above pattern, you can probably generate a regex. It won't be that tough.

Comment: so basically it would be just a*b*?

Comment: @OSUBuckeyeCompSci. You're almost there. Notice the strings at the ends. Your automata can repeat the string. So, it would be - `(a*b*)*`.

Comment: So based on the above FA how would you determine the start and end state?

Comment: Rather `(a+b+)*`, to prevent catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @OSUBuckeyeCompSci.. They are already given. They are not determined.

Comment: @OSUBuckeyeCompSci. The person giving you an FSA to work with will also give you start and end state. Else you cannot work it out.

Comment: @OSUBuckeyeCompSci: Usually they are marked in the diagram. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram

Answer (score 0):

If your (-) state is end state then:

```
b*(a+b+)*
```

If your (+) state is end state:

```
b*(a+b+)*a+
```